# better way to find depth of a node in tree

Tags: java, tree, depth

I want  to compute depth of a tree
I have written code below

My question is that :

1. what is the order of this code? Is it O(n) [n is number of tree Nodes]
2. Is there any other way which you think is better and faster?

Thanks in advance

```
public int height(Node n)
{
    if(n == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's O(n), regardless of what type of tree you have, since you're visiting every single node to establish the maximum depth.

The only more efficient way is to have extra information about the tree stored somewhere. If it's balanced, you know the *maximum* height based on the number of nodes.

Alternatively, you can cache the information. Have two extra variables `depth` and `dirty` and initially set `dirty` to true:

- When a caller requests the depth and `dirty` is true, call your function to work it out but the store that into `depth` and set `dirty` to false.
- When a caller requests the depth and `dirty` is false, just return `depth`.
- Whenever the structure of the tree is changed (insert or delete node), set `dirty` to true.

Comment: Implementing a cache, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your function is O(n).

Store the height in each node as you create it, and maintain that height as you add, remove, and balance the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see that your question asks for depth and the code is to find the height of the node.

I am not really sure, what you want height or depth. If you require the code for depth, this is not the way. See below:

```
Depth (n) = 1 + Depth(P(n))
```

is the recursive definition of depth.

For height, what you wrote is correct.

Check [Tree Operations](http://techieme.in/operations-on-a-binary-tree/) , I have written it for most of the operations on a tree with their asymptotic analysis

Comment: I know it's old but I also caught the same thing as 'dharam' did. The question was to calculate depth but solution provided returns the height, not depth.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, your code is O(n), because in the worst case you call height on the root node (and then you have to touch every node to find the longest path to a leaf).
2. TTS's code is the same as yours, and I don't think there is a faster way to do it.